# Troubleshoot ActiveX control installation

Tags: windows-7, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, activex

I've created a asp.net application that uses a 3rd party activex control and deployed it successfully on a test intranet. The clients are prompted to install the control and it runs fine. I am now attempting to get someone else to deploy it on their intranet and their clients are unable to download the activex control from the server. The normal internet explorer pop-up dialog appears saying "do you want to install the activex control", but nothing installs and no error message appears. Just a little red cross where the activex control should be. Their clients have ie8 and windows 7 same as me.

I've tried a few things like getting them to add the site explicitly to their intranet sites and prompting for all the activex options in Tools>Security>custom level but no luck and it is very difficult to get them to troubleshoot as I don't have remote access to their network.

Is there a log file somewhere or a list of actions I can get them to take to trace the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was their proxy server causing the problem...

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as accepted. It lets the system know a problem was resolved.